# Where IN to JOIN how?

Tags: mysql, sql

Writing down this using JOIN ..how?
because this is very slow..

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID
             FROM table1
             GROUP BY ID
             HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
             AND MAX(awaiting) = 1)
AND awaiting = 1
```

so, how can I write?

Comment: You need an index not a query rewrite.

Comment: but the answer below works perfect, very quick...300%...Any-Way..Why Negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT ID
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY ID
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
      AND MAX(awaiting) = 1
) AS t2 ON t1.ID = t1.ID AND t1.awaiting = t2.awaiting
WHERE t1.awaiting = 1;
```

Comment: this is exact, what I want...Thanks...I will accept it as Answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is the `join` version:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1 join
     (SELECT ID
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY ID
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 AND MAX(awaiting) = 1
     ) tsum
     on t1.id = tsum.id
WHERE t1.awaiting = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess `awaiting` is 0 or 1. If so in your inner query `MAX(awaiting) = 1` is redundant because of WHERE statement `awaiting = 1`

Also in this case you can use the following query.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 as T1
WHERE 
awaiting = 1
AND
(SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE ID=T1.ID)=2
```

Comment: that is more compact and nice, Thanks @MR.Valex